# Erro no codigo de javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou com um erro no exercício do meu curso alguém pode me ajudar?

```
(function(){
        var mes = prompt("Deseja calcular quantos meses? [0 à 3]");
        mes = parseFloat(mes);
        if(mes === 1){
            function mes1(P,I){
                montante1 = 'S = ' + P(1 + I);
                return montante;
            }

        }
        else if(mes === 2){
            function mes2(P,I){
                montante2 = 'S = ' + P(1 + I)*(1 + I);
                return montante;

            }
        }
         else if(mes === 3){
             function mes3(P,I){
                 montante3 = 'S = ' + P(1 + I)*(1 + I)*(1 + I);
                 return montante;
             }
         }
         var P = prompt("Digite a principal: ");
         var I = prompt("Digite a taxa de juros: ");
         var montantemes1 = mes1(P,I);
         var montantemes2 = mes2(P,I);
         var montantemes3 = mes3(P,I);
            document.write(montantemes1);
            document.write(montantemes2);
            document.write(montantemes3);
    })()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro? Poderia elaborar um [mcve]? E [edit] a pergunta descrevendo com palavras o que o código deveria fazer? Você define funções dentro de condicionais, mas as chama independente da condição, o que não faz sentido; se `mes` valer 1, apenas a função `mes1` será definida, mas mesmo assim você chama ao final as funções `mes2` e `mes3`. Por que?

Comment: O erro é o seguinte aparece o alert mas ele não mostra o resultado então o mes2 e mes3 ele é o outro calculo dos juros caso  o usuario digitar 2 ou 3. Eu posso atribuir a mesma condição em três ou mais funções como eu fiz?? se não eu ja sei que o problema foi esse mas se sim o problema é outro! Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso que gostaria de fazer:

```js
(function() {
  var montante1 = null;
  var montante2 = null;
  var montante3 = null;

  var mes = prompt("Deseja calcular quantos meses? [0 à 3]");
  mes = parseFloat(mes);

  var P = prompt("Digite a principal: ");
  var I = prompt("Digite a taxa de juros: ");

  if (mes === 1) {
    montante1 = 'S = ' + P * (1 + I);
  } else if (mes === 2) {
    montante2 = 'S = ' + P * (1 + I) * (1 + I);
  } else if (mes === 3) {
    montante3 = 'S = ' + P* (1 + I) * (1 + I) * (1 + I);
  }

  if(montante1){
    document.write(montante1);
  }
  
  if(montante2){  
    document.write(montante2);
  }
  
  if(montante3){
    document.write(montante3);
  }
  
})()
```

Dicas:

- pesquise sobre escopo de variáveis e funções em javascript: https://medium.com/weyes/entendendo-o-uso-de-escopo-no-javascript-3669172ca5ba

Comment: Muito obrigado marcio! Era isso mesmo obrigado